# Did splitting my linear regression sample improve my model?

Tags: regression, least-squares, model-evaluation

**Approach 1:** I regress $Y$ on $X$, obtaining estimates $\hat{\beta}$ and its covariance matrix $S$.

**Approach 2:** I first partition $X$ into $X_1, X_2$ using some method (e.g. k-means).
Then I separately regress $Y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$, obtaining results $\hat{\beta_1}, S_1, \hat{\beta_2}, S_2$.

Did approach 2 improve over approach 1?

I've been looking at the determinant of the covariance matrix, aka generalized variance, as a scalar measure of model performance (intuitively I want my estimates to have low variances). Since smaller samples naturally lead to higher-variance estimates, is there a way to take that into account?

Comment: No, it did not improve your model in any meaningful way: http://andrewgelman.com/2017/06/19/breaking-data-little-pieces-putting-back-together/

Comment: If the actual relationship is piece-wise linear, then surely splitting my sample  at the juncture would lead to better estimates? I'm looking for a quantitative metric to use, not asking a philosophical question.

Comment: Yes, but in that case fitting a linear regression was wrong in the first place, you should have fit a piecewise regression instead. So it's an unfair comparison that you are describing. 

Plotting the data first should let you choose if this is necessary. Or you may have strong a priori expectation for a discontinuity of some sort.

Comment: Also, whether intended as such or not, your question does get at important statistical (perhaps philosophical) concepts. I think it's worth considering them to see why this is misguided. But if all you want is a general quantitative metric of model performance, prediction error on a hold-out dataset is almost always good.

Answer (score 3):

Turning my comments above into an answer:

Splitting data into subsets and fitting models to each subset cannot improve your models, parameter estimates or inferences *provided your original model is properly specified*. As Andrew Gelman puts it [here](http://andrewgelman.com/2017/06/19/breaking-data-little-pieces-putting-back-together/), while considering the case of data being sampled multiple times from the same process:

> From a Bayesian standpoint, the result is the same, whether you
>   consider all the data at once, or stir in the data one-third at a
>   time. The problem would come if you make intermediate decisions that
>   involve throwing away information, for example if you take parts of
>   the data and just describe them as statistically significant or not.

As @whuber points out in the comments below, the assumption that the original model (fit to the full dataset) is specified properly is crucial. If splitting the dataset and fitting models to the subsets leads to improvement, it would be evidence that the original model was misspecified. I should note that there are, of course, other ways of identifying model misspecification.

Comment: It's difficult to see how such a blanket statement could generally be true.  The question seems to ask how to compare a more complex model to a simpler one in which it is nested.  Would you throw away all the machinery of model selection in this case under the assumption that it's impossible for any data to conform better to the more complicated model?  Counterexamples are easy to come by... .  I am not gainsaying Gelman: his remarks are predicated on the *assumption* that the data are an exchangeable sample from the same process.

Comment: @whuber I don't think we've interpreted the question in the same way. It seems to focus on potential gains from partitioning a dataset and fitting models to subsets vs. fitting a single model to the whole dataset simultaneously. I don't think such gains are possible unless the model for the whole dataset is misspecified. If there's a question here about complex vs. simple models in general, I've entirely missed it.

Comment: I see splitting a model into subsets and performing a separate fit on each one as constituting a more complex model.  As an example, suppose the model is split on the value of a binary explanatory variable: the procedure is tantamount to including that variable and all its interactions, as well as allowing for limited heteroscedasticity (the error variances in the two halves may differ).

Comment: @whuber In the example you describe, why would performance improve when modelling them separately unless the full model is misspecified? The heteroscedasticity may well be important, but one could include that in the full model. Perhaps the fact that you may not suspect the heteroscedasticity *a priori* is reasonable enough to weaken the claim I've made a bit. But does it invalidate it?

Comment: That's exactly the point: when a more complex model fits significantly better, that's *prima facie* evidence that the original (not the "full") model was mis-specified.  But this question doesn't assume, even implicitly, that the original model was correctly specified: it simply describes two models and asks whether one improves over the other.

Comment: @whuber Agreed. Would you agree with my claims if the original model (thanks for the terminology correction) is properly specified? If so, I will edit with that proviso.

Comment: I would see that hypothetical situation as being purely academic: after all, if the second model clearly and significantly improves on the first, doesn't that *a fortiori* falsify your supposition that the original is properly specified?

Comment: @whuber Yes, it would falsify it - but I don't think that my point is purely academic because there are other ways of identifying whether a model is misspecified.

Comment: I won't disagree with that!  But it looks like we have established that your statement "... cannot improve your models" is not correct, at least not without substantial elaboration concerning your assumptions.

Comment: @whuber Agreed - thanks for this discussion. I have edited to elaborate regarding those assumptions.